# Would sequence of nodes visited by BFS and DFS ever be the same?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Suppose a graph traversal of Depth First Search (DFS) and Breadth First Search (BFS) are implemented using stack and queue respectively.

Would there ever be a case where the sequence of vertex(s) traversed by both BFS and DFS are the same? What would be the property(s) of the graph that would allowed this to happen?

Let's also assume, for simplicity, this is a sparse graph and our graph is represented as adjacency list as shown:

```
For example: 
0 -> 1
1 -> 2
2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1
3 -> 2 -> 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest graph where both BFS and DFS would visit the nodes in the same order would be a linked list. Since a linked list is just a graph with just one node at each depth, both algorithms will visit nodes in the same order, assuming you start at one of the end points of the linked list for undirected graphs, or you start at the node with indegree=0 for directed graphs.

Comment: It depends on where you start to visit it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you are correct, I added more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible for some very simple graphs. They all look like this, where root is the first node you visit, and the order of the traversal is like on the picture, from left to right. Feel free to remove any nodes you want, I just draw the most complex structure possible.

As a general rule, only the rightmost child can have more than a single child. But you can have links pointing "back" to any node which was visited previously in the graph.

```
  r o o t
 /  |... \ 
1st 2nd  nth
          \
          node
            \
            ...
              \
              node
             / |.. \
            a  b    z
                     \
                    ....
```